# Implementing a Monad trait in scala with map as a derived primitive, not satisfying the criteria for use with for-comprehension

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am in the process of building my own little functional programming library for educational purposes in scala 2.13, and while doing so, I am having trouble meeting the requirement for the `map` operation for use in for-comprehensions.

Here, I am implementing map as a derived primitive using a combination of `flatMap` and `pure`, so that I don't have to provide an implementation for it each time I define a monad instance, but somehow, the compiler is not happy with that:

```scala
trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  def flatMap[A, B](fa: F[A])(g: A => F[B]): F[B]

  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] =
    flatMap(fa)(f andThen pure)
}

case class Id[A](get: A)

object Monad {
  val idMonad = new Monad[Id] {
    def pure[A](a: A) = Id(a)
    def flatMap[A,B](ma: Id[A])(f: A => Id[B]) =
      f(ma.get)
  }

  val example: Id[Unit] = for {
    _ <- Id(())
  } yield ()
```

Compiler error:

```scala
[error] value map is not a member of fp.Id[Unit]
[error]     _ <- Id(())
[error]          ^^^^^^
Error compiling project (Scala 2.13.13, JVM (17))
```

scala version: 2.13.13

Does anyone see any blatant mistake in what I've done that would not accept my definition for `map`?

I have defined map as a method to the monad instance `Id`, which enables the use of for-comprehension, but completely voids my intent of not having to provide an implementation for `map`, given that `pure` and `flatMap` are implemented.

```scala
case class Id[A](get: A) {
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Id[B]): Id[B] = f(get)
  // Adding map here will satisfy the requirement for for-comprehensions.
  def map[B](f: A => B): Id[B] = Id(f(get))
}
```

My goal is to have derived primitives such as map, as all Monads are Functors.

Comment: Well, for for-comprehension to work, you need a `map` (and `flatMap`) method on the `Id` class. Either explicitly or inheritance, or maybe via an extension class (implicit class)? Scala standard library won't "magically" look at your `Monad` definitions as it is currently written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you did not implement the `map` method on the `Id` class. Notice furthermore that while your `map` method takes an instance and two type parameters, for a `map` method call to be synthesized by the compiler you would rather need a `map` method defined *on* an instance.

What you have done so far is implementing part of the "type class pattern" in Scala. A common mechanism used to "bridge" between the type class instance and object instances is by using an `implicit class`, as well as adding your type class instance in the implicit scope, like in the following example:

```
trait Monad[F[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  def flatMap[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => F[B]): F[B]

  def map[A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] =
    flatMap(fa)(f andThen pure)
}

case class Id[A](get: A)

object Monad {

  implicit class MonadOps[F[_], A](fa: F[A])(implicit val M: Monad[F]) {
    def flatMap[B](f: A => F[B]): F[B] = M.flatMap[A, B](fa)(f)
    def map[B](f: A => B): F[B] = M.map[A, B](fa)(f)
  }

  implicit val idMonad: Monad[Id] = new Monad[Id] {
    def pure[A](a: A): Id[A] = Id(a)
    def flatMap[A, B](ma: Id[A])(f: A => Id[B]): Id[B] =
      f(ma.get)
  }
}

import Monad._

val fourtytwo = for {
  twentyone <- Id(21)
} yield twentyone * 2

assert(fourtytwo.get == 42)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/okNtGr9FRcWc9JAd4FrTfg/56).

For more information on implicit classes, you can read [this article](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) on the Scala website.

You can read more about type classes on [this article](https://scalac.io/blog/typeclasses-in-scala/) on the Typelevel blog.

Notice that this answer is valid for Scala 2. Scala 3 evolved everything revolving around implicits, including implicit classes. The introduction of extension methods to take their place lead to a few changes in how you work with type classes. If you're interested in type classes in Scala 3 the Scala website has [an article](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-type-classes.html) about them.